# Rails form_for locales no implicit conversion of Symbol to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm stuck, trying to create form_for for my comments model. I try to get post_id and user_id through locales, pass them to the form and create text_field for comment text. After that I'm getting "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error.
My code:

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: {user_id: current_user.id, post_id: post.id} %>

<%= form_for @comment, user_post_comments(user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id) do |f| %>
 <% f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

The mistake was in route. The correct version:

```
<%= form_for @comment, url:user_post_comments(user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id) do |f| %>
```